# Which Statistical Technique (ANCOVA or Taguchi methods) for this problem?

Tags: self-study, experiment-design, ancova

I have one qualitative factor (Treatments) and two uncontrollable factors, temperature and moisture, with one response variable. I'm confused whether I should use ANCOVA  with temperature and moisture as covariates or Taguchi methods can be used for this problem. Any advise and point to reference will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Primary goal of [Taguchi method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taguchi_methods) is to find control factor settings that generate acceptable responses despite natural environmental and process variability.In each experiment, Taguchi’s design approach employs two designs called the inner and outer array. The Taguchi experiment is the cross product of these two arrays. The control factors, used to tweak the process, form the inner array.

The noise factors, associated with process or environmental variability, form the outer array. Taguchi’s signal-to-noise ratios are functions of the observed responses over an outer array. A signal-to-noise ratio is a statistic calculated over an entire outer array. Its formula depends on whether the experimental goal is to maximize, minimize or match a target value of the quality characteristic of interest.
" from see [JMP.com](http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Taguchi_Designs.shtml)

A covariate may be of direct interest or it may be a confounding or interacting variable. The idea of [co-variance analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_covariance) is adjusting the treatment effect by introducing additonal terms in the model. You can make decisions on after adjustment with a [covariate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariate) - such as temperature and moisture in your case. The decision will complicated if there is significant interaction between treatment and one or more covariates. One of difference between two is that Taguchi method introduces concept of signal and noise ratio and tolerance into the "bucket". Means the you can have quality control - very popular in engineering where you can tolerate certain degree of deviation in quality and can be equated with cost associated with such measure.

In other hand, the covariance analysis simply discounts the variability associated with other correlated variable and its significance can be tested by ANOCOVA. If you just want to control the background noise I think both of method can do so, but ANOCOVA concept may simpler to explain, depending upon the target audience. In addition, Taguchi method can introduce concept of tolerance. Based on the explanation in the question, it may difficult to provide judgmental decision but the above points definitely help.